# linq c# grouping by month and year range

Tags: c#, linq, date, group-by

I have a list of records with dates. I want to group this list by month and year, so for example I could have dates that span a range from October 2012 until march 2013, then april 2013 until september 2013 and then October 2013 until march 2014 and finally april 2014 until sept 2014

so id want the data grouped into 4 groups, each group spanning a 6 month period
so
oct 2012 - march 2013
april 2013 - sept 2013
oct 2013 - march 2014
april 2014 - sept 2014

ive figured out how to group by a month range, but I cant figure out how to include the year (Im currently getting 2 groups), heres what i have so far

var season = List.GroupBy(item => ((item.StartDate.Month - 1) / 6));

Comment: Solve an easier problem. Could you see how to do your grouping correctly if the ranges were January through June and July through December?

Comment: You probably can group by how many 6 months passed since the min date. i.e. you can the min date by `var minDate = List.Min(l => l.StartDate)` then group by `var season = List.GroupBy(item => (item.StartDate - minDate).TotalMonths/6)` .. something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can group first by year and then use your groupping by month

```
var season = List.GroupBy(item => new { item.StartDate.Year,  month = ((item.StartDate.Month - 1) / 6)});
```

Or you can use combined tag for your values like

```
var season = List.GroupBy(item => item.StartDate.Year.ToString() + ((item.StartDate.Month - 1) / 6).ToString());
```

Comment: your first option gives me an error 'invalid anonymous type member declarator'

Comment: it should be fixed now, you need to name your annonymous property if it is calculated. In first property you don't have to do this because name will be taken from property name 'Year'

Answer (score 0):

calculating total months is the way to go

```
.GroupBy(item => (item.StartDate.Year * 12 + item.StartDate.Month + 2) / 6))
```